# Pass value from anchor to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I pass the value of name.report to the controller withoout passing it through a URL, this is in a side bar. I'm sorry if this is a really simple question, but I have searched quite a lot and couldn't find a solution

```
                        
   @foreach (var name in Model.namesReport)
   {

       <li href="#" class=""><a class="menu_name">   @name.ReportName</a>
   }
```

Comment: Can you show your controller and action header pls?

Comment: @Serge I havent got that part done yet, the idea is to get the report name onto a controller to be passed as a parameter of a stored procedure. Im trying to find a way of doing it without passing the report name in the url

Comment: When you use an ancor it is alway GET request and you will have to put report name in url, there is no choise here.  If you want to hide a report name ,  you have to choose POST and it means  you have to submit form.

Comment: Would it be a problem that I have only one View, as this web app is only a side bar a a form I only used a single view.

Comment: Managed to get the report name to be passed in the url, how do I get it in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult test(int? id) 
        {
            return null;
        }
```

**Ajax call**

```
        $("getReport".click(function()  {
            $ajax({
                url: '/Home/test',
                type:'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {id:"test"}


            });


        });
```

Comment: @Serge Would it be something like this?